# Why won't my Xamarin.Forms ListView Data Binding reflect in other Views?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, binding

My `MainPage.xaml` page is bound to `ClientsViewModel.cs`.  This page has a `ListView` bound to an `ObservableCollection` property.

The `NewClient.xaml` page and entry fields are also bound to the `ClientsViewModel.cs`.

When I save a new client using the `NewClient.xaml` form and navigate back to `MainPage.xaml` (using the navigation back arrow) I expect to see the newly added client in the `MainPage.xaml` `ListView` however I do not see this change.

How come the `ListView` in `MainPage.xaml` isn't showing the newly updated record? Where am I going wrong?

It may be worthwhile mentioning that my actual project will be using SQLite, so the `ObseravbleCollection` will eventually be obtaining records directly from an SQLite database, so any help or advice around this would be greatly appreciated also.

Refer below code, or clone from my GitHub repository https://github.com/minlopalis/XamarinForms-ListView-DataBinding.git

**(Model) Client.cs**

```
    public class Client
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
```

**(ViewModel) BaseViewModel.cs**

```
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
```

**(View Model) ClientViewModel.cs**

```
 public class ClientViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Client> clients;
        public ObservableCollection<Client> Clients 
        {
            get { return clients; } 
            set
            {
                clients = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public Command SaveClientCommand { get; }

        public ClientViewModel()
        {
            this.Clients = new ObservableCollection<Client>();

            SaveClientCommand = new Command(()=> {

                Client client = new Client()
                {
                    Name = Name,
                    Phone = Phone
                };

                Clients.Add(client);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Clients));
            });
        }



        private int id;
        public int Id 
        {
            get { return id; }
            set
            {
                id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string phone;
        public string Phone
        {
            get { return phone; }
            set 
            {
                phone = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

    }
```

**(View) MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:DataBinding.ViewModels"
             x:Class="DataBinding.MainPage">
    
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:ClientViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Client List"></Label>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Phone}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Button Text="Add Client"
                Clicked="AddClientButton_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**(View) NewClient.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:DataBinding.ViewModels"
             x:Class="DataBinding.Views.NewClient">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:ClientViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Add New Client" />

            <Label Text="Name"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>

            <Label Text="Phone"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding Phone}"/>

            <Button Text="Save"
                    Command="{Binding SaveClientCommand}"/>

            <!-- Added ListView -->
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Phone}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong at a first glance, although the `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Clients));` should not be needed, that's why it is an `ObservableCollection`. Your repo however gives a 404 so possibly it's private? :)

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Thanks for the tip regarding the `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Clients));`, I was wondering about that.   Also, I have updated my repo to Public.   Essentially my issue is when I navigate back to the `MainPage` the new client isn't shown in the `MainPage` `ListView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help, I have solved my issue.

There were two problems with my code.

**1. Two ViewModel Instances**

As pointed out by [Gerald Versluis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1506387/gerald-versluis) I had two instances of my `ViewModel`.  I fixed this issue by creating an instance of my view model in `Application.Resources` in my `App.xaml` page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DataBinding.App"
             xmlns:ClientViewModel="clr-namespace:DataBinding.ViewModels">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ClientViewModel:ClientViewModel x:Key="ClientViewModel" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And binding each page to the Static Resource (as below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:DataBinding.ViewModels"
             x:Class="DataBinding.Views.NewClient">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <StaticResource Key="ClientViewModel"/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Add New Client" />

            <Label Text="Name"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>

            <Label Text="Phone"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding Phone}"/>

            <Button Text="Save"
                    Command="{Binding SaveClientCommand}"/>

            
            <!-- Added ListView -->
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ClientList}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Phone}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Thanks Gerald Versluis for your help.  Check out his YouTube channel [here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBBZ2kXWmd8eXlHg2wEaClw).

**2. Missing ViewCell**

My `MainPage.xaml` was missing a `ViewCell` in the `ListView`. This was a simple typing oversight but was throwing a "'Specified cast is not valid" error. Big thanks to [Alexander Fauland](https://forums.xamarin.com/profile/AlexanderFauland) for his reply to [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/86266/using-listview-with-mvvm-pattern-i-get-invalidcastexception-specified-cast-is-not-valid) thread which helped me solve my missing ViewCell problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've downloaded your code from the repo and I think there is one big flaw in it causing this. You're setting your `BindingContext` in XAML on both pages. If you set a breakpoint in the constructor of the `ClientViewModel`, you will notice it gets called twice: once when the app boots, once when you click "Add Client".

This means you are looking at two separate instances of this class so your `Client` is in the wrong instance. You want to make sure that you are looking at the same view model.

Even more so, you might even want to make the separation of concerns even better by creating an extra, i.e.: `CreateClientViewModel` which is only responsible for creating the client and returning that object to the `ClientViewModel` which then in its turn adds that to the collection.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response, I copied your breakpoint in the constructor of the `ClientViewModel` and found it interesting that this was being called twice?  I'm not 100% sure why?  I understand what your saying about looking at two instances, but not sure how to implement only one ViewModel? Should I create my bindings programmatically in `MainPage.xaml.cs` and `NewClient.xaml.cs` e.g. `this.BindingContext = new DataBinding.ViewModels.ClientViewModel();`  I'm a beginner and not really sure how to implement your answer. Can you provide a code example or a website explaining this concept?

Comment: I think if you simply Google for MVVM and Xamarin.Forms there will be loads of results, like this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm

Specifying the view model like you did will simply instantiate a new one because it has no knowledge of the first one. Depending on what you want to do there is many ways to solve this.

Comment: Thanks @Gerald Versluis I have searched for MVVM and have read many articles and most are saying to DataBind the way I have been doing it.  However there must be something I have overlooked. I will continue my search. Thank you for your help, you have pointed me in the right direction with regards to my ViewModel being instantiated twice. :)  Fun fact: I came across your YouTube channel in my search, I'm a recent subscriber ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to pass data when navigate between pages, I suggest you can use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center).

MainPage:

```
 <StackLayout>
    <Label Text="Client List" />

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Phone}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Button Command="{Binding SaveClientCommand}" Text="Add Client" />
</StackLayout>

public partial class Page9 : ContentPage
{
    private ClientViewModel _clientmodel;
    public ClientViewModel clientmodel
    {
        get { return _clientmodel; }
        set
        {
            _clientmodel = value;
        }
    }

    public Page9()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new ClientViewModel(this.Navigation);
    }      
}

 public class ClientViewModel 
{       
    public ObservableCollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }   
    public Command SaveClientCommand { get; }
    private INavigation _navigation;

    public ClientViewModel(INavigation navitation)
    {
        Clients = new ObservableCollection<Client>();
        Clients.Add(new Client() { Name = "client1", Phone = "123" });

        _navigation = navitation;

        SaveClientCommand = new Command(async() => {

            await _navigation.PushAsync(new NewClient());
        });
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string, string[]>("test", "Add", (sender, values) =>
        {
            Client client = new Client() { Name=values[0],Phone=values[1]};
            Clients.Add(client);
        });
    } 
      
}
```

NewClient.xaml:

```
public partial class NewClient : ContentPage
{
    public NewClient()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = entry1.Text;
        string phone = entry2.Text;

        string[] values = { name,phone};
        MessagingCenter.Send<string, string[]>("test", "Add", values);
        Navigation.PopAsync();

    }
}
```

By the way, you don't need to call PropertyChanged for ObservableCollection, because [ObservableCollection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0) Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

Comment: Thanks, I will read up on `MessagingCenter` it might take a bit for me to get my head around as it is a completely new concept.  It appears from Gerald Versluis' answer that my Bindings are being set to different instances, so are therefore not updating the ListView correctly.  I am still unsure how to remedy this issue?  Thanks for your comments regarding the `ObseravableCollection` this was a gray area for me. :)

Comment: To be honest I feel that the `MessagingCenter` should be a last resort and certainly isn't the right solution for this. There is much better, readable and maintainable ways to pass the objects back and forth